# I have generated a fibonacci Series but now i want to mention on each number that which number is odd or even?

Tags: java

```
public class fiboaddeven {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
int a=-1;
int b=1;
int c=0;
for(int i=1;i<=12;i++){


    c=a+b;
    a=b;
    b=c;
    System.out.println(c);
}
    }

}
```

The Following output is 
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
I want
0odd
1odd
1odd
2even
3odd
5odd
8even
13odd
21even
34odd
55odd
89odd

Comment: FYI i think 0 is even.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is % operator with returns remainder.

```
String evenOrOdd = c % 2 == 0 ? " even" : " odd";
System.out.println(c + evenOrOdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply test the remainder when dividing by 2:

```
System.out.println(c + (( c % 2 == 0 ) ? "even" : "odd" ));
```